# SQL Server Extended Events - find particular string in the syntax

Tags: sql-server

How can I check with SQL Server Extended Events if some string appears in the SQL query statement?

For example: I want to find all the queries that contain the string `ord_id=4` from 12:00 to 15:00 every day.

How can I trace this with extended events?

Thanks,
Ohad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the session wizard,select sql statement starting  and in global fields ,select sql text like below

[image]

and in final screen, you can filter as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do i need to use %ord_id=4%?

Comment: are you saying it works with %%,i am not sure,i tested it long back

Comment: Do you know how can I find also the queries that also failed with the syntax ord_id=4? Now I get all the queries that not failed…

Comment: Did you meant the queries that failed,like with some errors

Comment: Yes - queries with errors that include this syntax. Is it possible to trace them?

Comment: try checking  for any  aborted events

Comment: @TheGameiswar,  No,  you do need the %_% for `like_i_sql_unicode_string` operator in the XE creation dialogbox (GUI), e.g.: col1 like_i_sql unicode_string   %test%

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Query to read Extended Events

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, event_data) XMLEventData FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'PathForTheFile\*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

if you write * this means read all files, if you know where to look you can write your file name instead of *

After this to make it easy to the eye use the Query below, you need to modify the query for your needs.

```
SELECT            

     xexml.value('(./action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(400)') as UserName                 

    ,xexml.value('(./action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(400)') as Client_Hostname 

    ,xexml.value('(./action[@name="collect_system_time"]/value)[1]', 'datetime') as ProcessTime                 

    ,xexml.value('(./data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') as SQLStatement                

 FROM                 
(                
 SELECT CONVERT(XML, event_data) XMLEventData FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'PathOfYourFiles\*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) f
) AS EventTable                 

CROSS APPLY XMLEventData.nodes('/event') n (xexml)                
WHERE cast(xexml.value('(./action[@name="collect_system_time"]/value)[1]', 'datetime')as time) between '12:00:00' and '15:00:00'
AND  xexml.value('(./data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') like '%ord_id=4%'
```